# Let $X$ be uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$. Let $Y = X^{\frac{1}{\beta}} . \beta\neq0$ Find the density function for $Y$.

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Let $X$ be uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$.

Let $Y = X^{\frac{1}{\beta}} . \beta\neq0$

Find the density function for $Y$.

My solution:

For $\beta>0$:

$F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(X^{\frac{1}{\beta}}\leq y)=P(X\leq y^\beta)=y^\beta.$

For $\beta<0$:

$F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(X^{\frac{1}{-\beta}}\leq y)=P(X\geq y^{-\beta})=1-y^{-\beta}.$

For conclusion:

For $\beta>0$:

$
f(y)=\begin{cases}
\beta y^{\beta-1}, & 0\leq y\leq1\\
0, & else
\end{cases}
$

For $\beta<0$:

$
f(y)=\begin{cases}
\beta y^{-\beta-1}, & y\geq 1\\
0, & else
\end{cases}
$

Is my solution correct?

In addition, I try to solve without using CDF.

I want to use $\frac{f_X(X)}{|\psi'(X)|}=f_{\psi(X)}(X)=f_Y(Y)$.

Define $Y=\psi(X)=X^\frac{1}{\beta}$

Then $\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-x^2}{2}}{\frac{1}{\beta}\cdot X^\frac{1}{\beta-1}}=f_Y$

Is my solution correct?

I'd be grateful for a feedback!